# Generate numbers that divide evenly

Tags: java, math, random

I was wondering if there was an easy way to generate 2 numbers and make sure that one is evenly divisible by the other.

This is what i have so far:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int  d = rand.nextInt(90)*2 + 1;
int dd = rand.nextInt(d)+1;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "evenly dividable by each other". For two numbers a, b, they evenly divide each other only when a == b if my understanding if your requirements is correct.

Comment: One of the tags is exactly what you need to do to solve this problem. Ask yourself how you'd solve this on paper and it should be pretty obvious.

Comment: no i mean 2 numbers that will go into eachother evenly like 10/5  or 36/3 WITHOUT  an remainder

Comment: You're not making any sense.  You have 4 numbers there.

Comment: If you want a number that is evenly divisible by another number, simply multiply the second number by some third number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to generate two numbers a and b where a divides b I.e. there exists an int k where a*k =b you can randomly generate a and then randomly generate k and multiply the two to get b.